# How to inherit a class constructor that gets a class object c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

Hello i don't know how to create constructor for rectangle class that inherits from point class. I would like to make that constructor of rectangle take object of class point (it's in the /**/ comment)

```
class point
{
       double x_, y_, z_;

public:

    point(const double& a1 = 0, const double& a2 = 0, const double& a3 = 0)
    {
        x_ = a1;
        y_ = a2;
        z_ = a3;
    }

    double x() const { return x_; }
    double y() const { return y_; }
    double z() const { return z_; }
    double& x() { return x_; }
    double& y() { return y_; }
    double& z() { return z_; }
};

class rectangle : public point
{
    double a_, b_;

public:
    rectangle(const double& a1 = 0, const double& a2 = 0, const double& a3 = 0, const double& a4 = 0, const double& a5 = 0) : point(a1, a2, a3)
    {
        a_ = a4;
        b_ = a5;
    }

    /*
    rectangle(point p1, const double& a1, const double& a2)
    {
        x_ = p1.x();
        y_ = p1.y();
        z_ = p1.z();
        a_ = a1;
        b_ = a2;
    }
    */
    double& a() { return a_; }
    double& b() { return b_; }
    double a() const { return a_; }
    double b() const { return b_; }
    double field() const { return  a_ * b_; }
};
```

Also would like to ask if i can somehow fuse these two functions:

```
double x() const { return x_; }
double& x() { return x_; }
```

Comment: If you expose `double& x() { return x_; }`, just make `x` public instead (and all the other members as well).

Comment: Well, i would like to but later in code i do things like p1.x() = 1; (It's required by my professor)

Comment: Then change the code to `p1.x = 1;`. There's nothing to gain from using functions in this case.

Comment: Agree with @Snakerred, usually, having an interface is a better approach than making public internal properties directly.

Comment: @AdrianMaire "Usually" implies existence of cases where it's not true, and the case in the question is one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get away with

```
rectangle(point p1, const double& a1, const double& a2) : point(p1), a_(a1), b_(a2) {}
```

if you don't have other constructors in `point` else you will need to add

```
point(const point& other) = default; // copy construcor
```

at which point you will also need to look at the [rule of three or five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `x_`, `y_` and `z_` in the constructor of `rectangle` because they are private in the base class. You can either make them `protected` or simply use the `point` class' constructor:

```
rectangle(point p1, const double& a1, const double& a2)
: point(p1.x(), p1.y(), p1.z())
{
    a_ = a1;
    b_ = a2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the initialization list, just like you did with the first constructor:

```cpp
rectangle(point p1, const double& a1, const double& a2):point(p1)
{ 
    a_ = a1;
    b_ = a2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by this way:

```
using Animal::Animal;
```

There is a constructor inheritance using `using` keyword in c++ (pun intended). It worked for me.

```
// C++ program to demonstrate inheritance

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// base class
class Animal {

public:
     explicit Animal(){
         cout << "Constructor of Animal called";
     }
};

// derived class
class Dog : public Animal {

    using Animal::Animal;

public:

    Dog(){
        cout << "I can bark! Woof woof!!" ;
    }

};

int main() {
 Animal Obj1; // This will invoke the constructor of Animal class
 Dog obj2;    // This will also invoke Constructor of Animal class bcz of Using Keyword

    return 0;
}
```